# Asp.Net Core - Read Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need your help again. I have been working on a project in asp.net and I have had some doubts.

The project consists of reading an xml file and saving the data in a database.
I was able to read the data, but now I have a question
The question is...

I have this xml file.

```html
    -<products>


-<product>

<name>Ball</name>

<price>15</price>

<quantity>2</quantity>


-<description>

<comment>aaa</comment>

</description>


-<description>

<comment>bbb</comment>

</description>


-<age>

<number>12</number>

</age>

</product>
</products>
```

And this is the program.

```
 private List<Product> ProcessImport(string path)
    {
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path);
        List<Product> products = xDocument.Descendants("product").Select
            (p => new Product()
            {
               Id = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("id").Value),
               Name=p.Element("name").Value,
               Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("quantity").Value),
               Price = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("price").Value),
               Description = p.Element("description").Element("comment")


            }).ToList();

        foreach(var product in products)
        {
            var productInfo = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(product.Id));
            if (productInfo != null)
            {
                productInfo.Id = product.Id;
                productInfo.Name = product.Name;
                productInfo.Quantity = product.Quantity;
                productInfo.Price = product.Price;
                productInfo.Description= product.Description;


            }

            else 
            {


                db.Products.Add(product);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return products;


    }
```

My question is, the program above only reads the first description.

What do I have to insert so that he can read both descriptions?
(I think the ideal would be to create two tables and then make the connection between them)

But now I wanted help to get this done.

Thanks!!

Comment: Structurally, shouldn't the `description` nodes be contained within a single parent `descriptions` node?  Much in the same way that semantically it appears that `products` can contain multiple `product` nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a note,your xml file does not contain `id` node,but you need to read the `id` node data in your `ProcessImport` method.If you do not contain `id` node,you could not read the data in your code.

For your requirement,here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Description[] Description { get; set; }
}
public class Description
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private List<Product> ProcessImport()
{
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
    List<Product> products = xDocument.Descendants("product").Select
        (p => new Product()
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("id").Value),
            Name = p.Element("name").Value,
            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("quantity").Value),
            Price = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("price").Value),
            Description = p.Descendants("description").Select(d => new Description()
            {
                Comment = d.Element("comment").Value
            }).ToArray()


        }).ToList();

    //do your stuff...
    return products;
}
```

Result:
[image]
My test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
  <product>
    <id>100</id>
    <name>Ball</name>
    <price>15</price>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <description>
      <comment>aaa</comment>
    </description>
    <description>
      <comment>bbb</comment>
    </description>
    <age>
      <number>12</number>
    </age>
  </product>
</products>
```